# iOS: Swipe mobile app until text is visible

Tags: python, ios, selenium, swipe, appium-ios

I am trying to **swipe down the application and stop the swipe when the "text" is visible.**

I've tried but I get **NoSuchElementException** on "**el**" part. It is not even proceeding to swipe action:

```
   el = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(),'sometexthere')]')

self.driver.execute_script('mobile: scroll', {"element": el, "toVisible": True})
```

Do you know any other way to swipe to text in iOS app?

Language: Python
Fmwrks: Selenium, Appium

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
el = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(),'sometexthere')]')
el.send_keys("0.5") // For automating scroll
```

Work for me in java code
Read this appium docs: https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/

[image]